# Calculating the time before an investor makes profits on a cash flow

Tags: finance

Question: One year ago an investor purchased a old house for £100,000 with the purpose of refurbishing it and then either letting or selling it. For the refurbishment the investor paid £50,000 one year ago for the materials. Until now (i.e. during the past year) further £40,000 were paid as compensation for the builders in equal quarterly installments. The annual effective rate is 3%.

Assume the investor will let the property to tenants who are going to
pay £1,600 p.c.m. at the end of each month. The tenants will enter the property
in 6 months and the first payment is due after a month from the time they enter
the property. How long does it take before the investor starts making profits?

I've attempted this question once and ended up getting a MATH error on my calculator. I tried equating the value of the Outflows (costs of the house and builders) at t = 0 to the value of the sequence of monthly payments at t=0 and solving for n. Is this the correct way of approaching this question? If so, could someone help me arrive at the answer of 12.31 years? Thanks in advance.

[Visual Reference of my Method here on Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCQ5V.png)

Comment: Why don't you show us what you already made ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have made an edit to show you

Comment: @Quanto from t=0 I reckon.

Comment: From your image, I think the mistake is the compensation for the builders should be 10000 on a quarterly basis. If you take 40000, you'll never be able to get your investment back, which is why you get a "math error".

Comment: @Raskolnikov I used 40,000 because the annuity is payable quarterly, which I think is correct

Comment: Yes, but the annuity should be 40000/4. That's the problem. See also Quanto's answer where he also used 40000/4, although expressed in thousands of pounds.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Surely that would imply 10,000 pounds split into 4 payments of roughly 2500 pounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the number of months of rent payments is

$$n = -\frac{\ln\left[1-\frac{C}{1.6}r(1+r)^6\right]}{\ln(1+r)} \tag{1}$$

where $C$ is the totol cost at $t=0$, i.e.

$$C=150(1+r)^{12}+10(1+r)^9+10(1+r)^6+10(1+r)^3+10$$

and $r$ is the monthly compounding interest rate, backed out from the annual effective rate given.

$$r=(1+0.03)^{\frac{1}{12}}-1$$

$n$ comes out as 147.7 months, or 12.31 years.

---

Added responding to the comments:

The value $R$ of the total rents at $t=0$ is

$$R=\frac{1.6}{(1+r)^7}+\frac{1.6}{(1+r)^8}+ \space... \space  +
\frac{1.6}{(1+r)^{6+n}},
$$

a finite geometric series that can be summed up analytically. Then, setting $R=C$ leads to the formula (1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your logic in calculating S, but how did you reach the formula for n involving the logarithms? That would help me understand better.

Comment: See the added explanation in the answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Cheers.